# E/flutter ( 8922): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart':

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to integrate firebase auth in my Flutter app.
The code is Errorless and running successfully.

I also added everyfunction as documentation.
I crosschecked every function from login screen but, after entering country code and phone number an Unhandled Exception occurs.

And it is - - -

```
E/flutter ( 8922): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:firebase_auth/src/firebase_auth.dart': Failed assertion: line 805 pos 7: 'phoneNumber != null || multiFactorInfo != null': Either phoneNumber or multiFactorInfo must be provided.
```

My code in login screen code

```
import 'package:country_picker/country_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/colors.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/common/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/common/widgets/custom_button.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/features/auth/controller/auth_controller.dart';

class LoginScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  static const routeName = '/login-screen';
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginScreen> {
  final phoneController = TextEditingController();
  Country? country;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    phoneController.dispose();
  }

  void pickCountry() {
    showCountryPicker(
        context: context,
        onSelect: (Country _country) {
          setState(() {
            country = _country;
          });
        });
  }

  void sendPhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = phoneController.text.trim();
    if (country != null && phoneNumber.isNotEmpty) {
      ref
          .read(authControllerProvider)
          .signInWithPhone(context, '+${country!.phoneCode}$phoneController');
    } else {
      showSnackBar(context: context, content: 'Fill out all the fields');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Enter your phone number'),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const Text("WhatsApp will need to verify your phone number."),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: pickCountry,
              child: const Text("Pick country"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 5),
            Row(
              children: [
                if (country != null) Text('+${country!.phoneCode}'),
                const SizedBox(
                  width: 10,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: size.width * 0.7,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: phoneController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'phone number',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height * 0.6,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 90,
              child: CustomButton(
                onPressed: sendPhoneNumber,
                text: "Next",
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Auth controller

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/features/auth/repository/auth_repository.dart';

final authControllerProvider = Provider((ref) {
  final authRepository = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
  return AuthController(authRepository: authRepository);
});

class AuthController {
  final AuthRepository authRepository;

  AuthController({
    required this.authRepository,
  });

  void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) {
    authRepository.signInWithPhone(context, phoneNumber);
  }
}
```

Auth Repository code

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/common/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:whatsapp_ui/features/auth/screens/otp_screens.dart';

final authRepositoryProvider = Provider(
  (ref) => AuthRepository(auth: FirebaseAuth.instance, firestore: FirebaseFirestore.instance,),
);

class AuthRepository {
  final FirebaseAuth auth;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore;

  AuthRepository({
    required this.auth,
    required this.firestore,
  });

  void signInWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNumber) async {
    try {
      await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
          await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        },
        verificationFailed: (e) {
          throw Exception(e.message);
        },
        codeSent: ((verificationId, forceResendingToken) async {
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            OTPScreen.routeName,
            arguments: verificationId,
          );
        }),
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(context: context, content: e.message!);
    }
  }
}
```

And If you want to inspect the whole project.

Here is the github link

https://github.com/Jabidgithub/App-with-backend-/tree/ErrorPart

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem deleting folder (caches gradle) /home//.gradle/caches/. The first build takes a while, but it worked....

Comment: It is not working even now

Comment: I solved the issue, Basically I didn't added the  ' phoneNumber: phoneNumber,' line in verifyingPhoneNumber in auth_repository.dart file. ;)